# CSS percentage width and percentage padding error in all broswers?

Tags: css

Look at this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/nvcode/BnGyu/2/

Now it is clearly obvious that the browser can work out the width correctly as the first div is fully filled but on the second div I place a width of 98% and 1% padding either side, making a total of 100%.

The browser knows that 100% is full width of the parent, so why is the child div not fill the space of the parent?

Even if you change the value of the widths it breaks even more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default any block-level element is going expand to fill the width of its containing element. In this case specifying the width of the inner element is redundant. In general it's better (and less confusing) to use explicit metrics for your layout over percentages.

[This sums it up nicely.](http://www.impressivewebs.com/width-100-percent-css/)

Comment: Thanks for this, was scratching my head wondering why this was happening!

Comment: You're welcome. You'd run into a related issue if you were to, say, make a block 100% wide and then also add padding to it. You end up with content that always wants you to scroll to the right indefinitely because the block keeps filling the page and then padding it.

Comment: I can't vote you up because I don't have enough rep lol, I will when I do, and accept when I can :)

Comment: yes I understand now, does the opposite apply to inline elements?

Comment: Re: inline elements... No, it does not. Experiment and see for yourself. Setting the width of an inline element causes it to display as block. But this can also be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

@nvcode; first thing `div` is a `block` element & `block` element takes full width of his `parent` by default. So, if you give `padding & margin` to it not effect the structure. But some reason you define `width:100%` & want `padding` to it then you can use `box-sizing: border-box` property for this.

```
div{
        width:100%;
        padding-left:2%;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
        box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

check this http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html

but it's not work in IE7.